# Please clarify Remote Desktop Connection Broker high availability

Tags: remote-desktop, high-availability, windows-server-2016

I have a remote desktop environment on server 2016 that has 2 remote desktop connection brokers(RDCB) and 4 session hosts.

It is set up as an active/active setup using DNS round robin, as explained in this article: [RDCB High Availability](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2012/06/27/rd-connection-broker-high-availability-in-windows-server-2012/)

If a user connects to rdp.mycompany.com then the client pc will get the ip of one of my RDCB's because of the DNS round robin.
What if that server is no longer available: how or when will the user get the ip of the other server?
You could try to do it manually by rebooting the client pc or by doing ipconfig /flushdns but it could be that the DNS server still gives you the same ip, even if that server is unavailable.
I read that the DNS server does not check if the ip is reachable.

So how is this "high availability"? It feels like load balancing with 50% of the clients unable to connect when one of my servers becomes unavailable.
 Is there a way to make sure that all my clients can keep connecting even if one of the servers is unavailable? I would like to be able to update and reboot each RDCB without disrupting my clients.